How to stop visual studio DO NOT add 'require' header for my javascript file?
When I write js code in visual studio, sometimes stange 'require' headers was added to the header of my js file, I don't know whether it was done by visual studio or resharper(this is the only extension I installed).
Does anyone knows how to stop this?
the content of the header like this:
const { every } = require("core-js/library/fn/dict");


You should check the plugin or update the visual studio.
Sometimes the autocomplete or auto-import is happend when you enter the 'tab' or 'enter'  when they running.
It is like when you code the 'func',then it'll maybe import func from "@/core/func" in the script of top.
